# Can you make this JavaScript code smaller or more efficient?

Tags: javascript, performance, coding-efficiency

Using pure vanilla JavaScript can you make this smaller? Or even more efficient?
It's a "copy" of Jquery's '$' function. Though this works different, here is the code:

```
function $(id,from = document) {
    if(!'#.<'.includes(id.charAt(0))) id = '#' + id;
    if (id.charAt(0) == '<') id = id.charAt(id.length-1) == '>' ? id.substring(1,id.length-1) : id.substring(1,id.length);
    return from.querySelectorAll(id).length == 1 ? from.querySelectorAll(id)[0] : from.querySelectorAll(id).length == 0 ? false : from.querySelectorAll(id);
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to optimize this function, you're better off working on the callers, getting them to cache the results of the function instead of calling it unnecessarily.

Comment: This isn't https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

At least you can extract the result of `from.querySelectorAll(id)` into a variable instead of evaluating it multiple times.

And in another, just as Barmar suggested, cache the result of this function invocation somewhere out of it and keep this function simple and stupid(KISS).